# Materialize button changes alignment when it's display css is dynamically changed

Tags: html, materialize

So I am trying to dynamically change the button on my navbar and manage to do so however, the buttons vertical alignment goes off whenever I do it.

Navbar initailly:
[image]

Now, when a user clicks sign in and signs into his google account successfully, I intend to remove the sign in button and simply replace it with a profile button. However, when I do that, the vertical alignment of the profile button gets messed up.
[image]

Button Css:

```html
      .sign-in-btn {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
        border: 2px solid #1565c0;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
        color: #1565c0;
      }
      .sign-in-btn:hover {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
        border: 2px solid #1565c0;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        background-color: #1565c0;
        color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
      }
      .profile-btn {
        display: none;
      }
```

The navbar is the standard [extended navbar with tabs](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html) from materialize. Here is the code snippet from the navbar where links for the top part of the navbar are applied.

```html
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
              <a
                id="sign-in-btn"
                class="waves-effect waves-light btn sign-in-btn modal-trigger"
                href="#sign-in-modal"
              >
                Sign In
              </a>
              <a
                id="profile-btn"
                class="profile-btn waves-effect waves-light btn sign-in-btn modal-trigger"
                href="#"
              >
                My Profile
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a
                class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-3 generate-btn"
              >
                Generate Free Report
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

How I dynamically change the buttons on google sign in:

```js
      var signinChanged = function(val) {
        console.log("Signin state changed to ", val);
        if (val) {
          document.getElementById("sign-in-btn").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("profile-btn").style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("sign-in-btn").style.display = "flex";
          document.getElementById("profile-btn").style.display = "none";
        }
      };
```

Does anyone happen to know why this is happening ?

Comment: You haven't really given us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example – what CSS code does the UL class contain, to give an example.

Comment: @RickardElimää it is using standard materialize css (extended navbar with tabs): https://materializecss.com/navbar.html